# jQuery not Working $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery not working while using this code and the funtion get:

```
window.onload = function(){
$.get("http://mixsoft.cf/s/status.php?ip=190.60.215.195&port=8080", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
};
```

Comment: Are you running into CORS? I would look up the console if I don't own the domain, plus the data returned is assumed `application/json` whereas it's not a valid json for `JSON.parse` to work.

Comment: `Not working` is not a question. You should ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your callback to  `.complete` function & use `data.responseText` instead of `data` .

```js
$.get('http://mixsoft.cf/s/status.php?ip=190.60.215.195&port=8080').complete(function(data){
    console.log(data.responseText )
    alert(data.responseText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- Don't forget to  Import the following tag in your HTML page.

  ```
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```

Anyway, you don't have problem of CORS , since the response is scraped : 
[image]

Comment: It's too early for this answer :)

Comment: But the answer is fair enough.